# Header region causing the page to be too wide

Tags: theming

When viewing [my website](http://onlinebanter.com) on Internet Explorer there seems to be a big space on the right where the page has scroll bars to take in the full width. I think its to do with my header image. It seems ok in Firefox and chrome. Can anyone suggest a way to get this working on IE?

Comment: May you add a screenshot? It would help to see what you are seeing. Plus, the question would be helpful to future readers, even if the site is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of your fb_reset facebook iframes.

```
<div class=" fb_reset" id="fb-root">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js" async="true"></script>
<div style="top: -10000px; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute;">
```

If you remove the css rules in the style and change to

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

Add to css:

```
.fb_reset {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: And its only ie7. The others manage to figure it out.

Comment: exactlly .Its becasue Iframes